# Message chain is appearing in inbox (with preview), but I cannot open the full message

Tags: bug, jobs-messages

I had sent a job application without logging in, I used the link in the Stack Overflow email to view the message, and it requested that I log in, I did so, and the message is showing up in my inbox, but when I click on it to open it, I'm directed to a 'Page not found'.